# How can I update my openGL screen for it to display each frame?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I am trying to simulate knock-back so that as soon as you collide with a rect you will receive knock-back but I do not know how to update the screen so that you can see the player moving backwards due to it, we can see this in the `checkCollisionRect()` function where I have tried using the `glutDisplayFunc(display)` to display each frame of the player moving backwards but it does not work and only updates the screen once the loop is over instead of every iteration of the loop.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#ifdef __unix__
# include <unistd.h>
#elif defined _WIN32
# include <windows.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep(1000 * (x))
#endif

int width=1000; //Screen width
int height=500; //Screen height
int px=200; //Player pos x
int py=100; //Player pos y
float playerSpeed=5.0;

void init(){
 glClearColor(0.3,0.3,0.3,0);
 gluOrtho2D(0,width,height,0);
}

void display(){
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 //-----------------------Draw----------------------
 checkCollisionRect(px,py,10,10,200,200,100,100);
 drawRect(200,200,100,100); //rect
 drawRect(px,py,10,10); //player
 //-------------------------------------------------
 glutSwapBuffers();
 glutPostRedisplay();
}

void drawRect(int tlx,int tly,int boxWidth,int boxHeight){
 glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
 glVertex2f(tlx,tly+boxHeight); //Bottom Left
 glVertex2f(tlx,tly); //Top Left
 glVertex2f(tlx+boxWidth,tly); //Top Right
 glVertex2f(tlx+boxWidth,tly+boxHeight); //Bottom Right
 glEnd();
}

void checkCollisionRect(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2) {
 if (x1>x2+w2 || x1+w1<x2 || y1>y2+h2 || y1+h1<y2)
  glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
 else {
  glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
  int i;
  if (x1 < x2) {       // player hit the left wall
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    px -= i;
    sleep(0.1);
    display();
   }
  }
  if (x1+w1 > x2+w2) { // player hit the right wall
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    px += i;
    sleep(0.1);
    display();
   }
  }
  if (y1 < y2) {       // player hit the top wall
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    py -= i;
    sleep(0.1);
    display();
                
   }
  }
  if (y1+h1 > y2+h2) { // player hit the bottom wall
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    py += i;
    sleep(0.1);
    display();
   }
  }
 }
}
    
void drawSquare(px,py,size){
 glPointSize(size);
 glBegin(GL_POINTS);
 glVertex2i(px,py);
 glEnd();
}

void Buttons(unsigned char key,int x,int y){
 if(key=='a'){px-=playerSpeed;}     
 if(key=='d'){px+=playerSpeed;} 
 if(key=='w'){py-=playerSpeed;}
 if(key=='s'){py+=playerSpeed;}
}               

int main(int argc, char** argv){ 
 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
 glutInitWindowSize(width,height);
 glutCreateWindow("OpenGL");
 init();
 glutDisplayFunc(display);
 glutKeyboardFunc(Buttons);
 glutMainLoop();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: ``glutDisplayFunc`` sets the display function. It does not call it.

Comment: then how can I call it?

Comment: In a typical computer game you don't get to sleep or make these "inside loops". You have to let your rendering code run from top to bottom and then finish promptly. So you need some variables to remember that the player is getting knocked back, and how many frames of knockback are left.

Comment: Is there no way of doing this more efficiently, I have thought of doing it the way you suggest but that would make the code quite dirty and frankly unreadable.

Comment: `display` is the display function and is called form the glut main loop. Consider `display` as the content of the application loop. Do not call `display` yourself and certainly not in a loop, but calculate the animation for a single frame in `display` depending on the time or the frame counter.

Comment: Well, if its the only way I will do so

Comment: @Rabbid76 if you write it as an answer with some examples I will give you the bounty, because I am unable to award a comment with a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `display` is recursive: it invokes `checkCollisionRect` which invokes `display` in the inner loops, sleeping in the process. In order to fix this you need to introduce a dedicated update function which needs to be registered by invoking `glutIdleFunc`. It will be invoked by glut when all the events have been processed. Inside of this function you should perform a single iteration of game state update, invoke `glutPostRedisplay` (which should not be invoked from `display` btw) and return, letting glut execute display function and process input events.

Comment: Im not sure I understand, so do I have to make a dedicated update function or what?

Comment: @BOOTRE Yes, you need to implement some dedicated update function, basically to rework `checkCollisionRect` so it won't invoke `display` and return after each iteration. This also implies that you need to store state somewhere so it will be available inside of `display` function and inside of the next call to `checkCollisionRect` so it could resume iteration from the last checkpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, although I have been unable to find a way to update the screen I have found a way to implement Knock back any way. This is using a loop inside the main draw function.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#ifdef __unix__
# include <unistd.h>
#elif defined _WIN32
# include <windows.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep(1000 * (x))
#endif

#define or ||
#define and &&

int width=1000; //Screen width
int height=500; //Screen height
int px=200; //Player pos x
int py=100; //Player pos y
float playerSpeed=1.0;
int knockBackBoolRight=0;
int knockBackBoolLeft=0;
int knockBackBoolBottom=0;
int knockBackBoolTop=0;
int knockBackCounter=0;

void drawRect(int tlx,int tly,int boxWidth,int boxHeight){
 glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
 glVertex2f(tlx,tly+boxHeight); //Bottom Left
 glVertex2f(tlx,tly); //Top Left
 glVertex2f(tlx+boxWidth,tly); //Top Right
 glVertex2f(tlx+boxWidth,tly+boxHeight); //Bottom Right
 glEnd();
}

void checkCollisionRect(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2) {
 if (x1>x2+w2 || x1+w1<x2 || y1>y2+h2 || y1+h1<y2){
 }
 else {
  if (x1 < x2) {       // player hit the left wall
   knockBackBoolLeft=1;
  }
  if (x1+w1 > x2+w2){ // player hit the right wall
   knockBackBoolRight=1;
  }
  if (y1 < y2){       // player hit the top wall
   knockBackBoolTop=1;
  }
  if (y1+h1 > y2+h2){ // player hit the bottom wall
   knockBackBoolBottom=1;
  }
 } 
}
    
void drawSquare(px,py,size){
 glPointSize(size);
 glBegin(GL_POINTS);
 glVertex2i(px,py);
 glEnd();
}

void Buttons(unsigned char key,int x,int y){
 if(key=='a'){px-=playerSpeed;}     
 if(key=='d'){px+=playerSpeed;} 
 if(key=='w'){py-=playerSpeed;}
 if(key=='s'){py+=playerSpeed;}
}     

void init(){
 glClearColor(0.3,0.3,0.3,0);
 gluOrtho2D(0,width,height,0);
}

void userDisplay(){
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 //---------------------Objects---------------------
 //-----------------------Draw----------------------
 drawRect(200,200,100,100); //rect
 drawRect(px,py,10,10); //player
 //---------------------Checks----------------------
 checkCollisionRect(px,py,10,10,200,200,100,100);
 
 if(knockBackBoolTop==1 or knockBackBoolBottom==1 or knockBackBoolLeft==1 or knockBackBoolRight==1){
  playerSpeed=0;
 }
 else{
  playerSpeed=1.0;
 }
 
 if(knockBackCounter<=15){
  if(knockBackBoolLeft==1){    // player hit the left wall
    knockBackCounter++;
    px-=3;
    sleep(0.01);
  }
  if(knockBackBoolTop==1){     // player hit the top wall
    knockBackCounter++;
    py-=3;
    sleep(0.01);
  }
  if(knockBackBoolRight==1){   // player hit the right wall
    knockBackCounter++;
    px+=3;
    sleep(0.01);
  }
  if(knockBackBoolBottom==1){ // player hit the bottom wall
    knockBackCounter++;    
    py+=3;
    sleep(0.01);
  }
 }
 else{
   knockBackCounter=0;
   knockBackBoolBottom=0;
   knockBackBoolTop=0;
   knockBackBoolLeft=0;
   knockBackBoolRight=0;
 }
 //-------------------------------------------------
 glutSwapBuffers();
 glutPostRedisplay();
}

void main(int argc, char** argv){ 
 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
 glutInitWindowSize(width,height);
 glutCreateWindow("OpenGL");
 init();
 glutDisplayFunc(userDisplay);
 glutKeyboardFunc(Buttons);
 glutMainLoop();
}
```